# WordPress Conditional Post Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very simple problem, I would like to add a conditional if statement for the following array. I would ONLY like to show the attachments in a widget if there is at least 10 attachments, otherwise I don't want to display the widget.

```
  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'post_parent' => null,
        );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
```

How would I create an if statement for a specific number of attachments grabbed by this array? For example, "if ($attachments > 10) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have will only ever get a maximum of 10 posts, `'numberposts' => 10,`. To retrieve all posts that are attachments you can use `'numberposts' => -1,`. Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/.

Then you can check to see if there are at least 10 attachments:

```
if (count($attachments) >= 10) { 
    // display widget        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The args you pass into `get_posts` are calling for `10` posts, so you will never get more than that in the response.

```
'numberposts' => 10,
```

However, if you want the condition of display to be that it gets exactly 10:

```
if (count($attachments) === 10) {
  // proceed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your after?

```
if (count($attachments) > 10) {
  // code here
}
```

get_posts() returns an array of posts, so you can just count the number of elements in the array it returns.

Comment: It will never be true, because there is `'numberposts' => 10`, so it will return at most 10 attachments.